# Non-equivalence of two variants of the excision axiom

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question is motivated by

[Does excision imply that these inclusions are isomorphisms in homology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1806161)

There are two variants of the excision axiom for a homology theory:

(E)  Let $U, A \subset X$. If $\overline{U} \subset int(A)$, then the inclusion map $i : (X \backslash U, A \backslash U) \to (X,A)$ induces isomorphisms $i_\ast : H_n(X \backslash U, A \backslash U) \to H_n(X,A)$
for each $n$.

(E-open) As above, but restricted to open $U$.

When axiomatic homology theory was introduced by Eilenberg and Steenrod, they used axiom (E-open). However, they also showed that singular homology theory satisfies (E).

In the literature (E) prevails, but it is certainly not a universally accepted standard.

It seems that (E) is strictly stronger than (E-open). To verify this we would need an example of a homology theory satisfying (E-open) but not (E), but I could not find any.

Does anybody know such an example?

Edit:

Eilenberg and Steenrod define their axioms for homology theories living on an *admissible category* $\mathfrak{A}$ of pairs of spaces and maps of such pairs. This means that $\mathfrak{A}$ contains a single point space and is closed with respect to a few elementary  operations. Some well-known theories live on the category $\mathfrak{T}^2$ of all pairs of topological spaces (for example singular homology), other theories are only defined on smaller categories.

The answer to my question depends on $\mathfrak{A}$. For example, if $\mathfrak{A} = \mathfrak{C}^2$ = category of all compact pairs, then (E) and (E-open) are equivalent simply because only an open $U$ gives us a compact pair $(X \backslash U, A \backslash U)$.

This means that the desired example must live on an admissible $\mathfrak{A}$ having the following property ($\ast$):

Call a triple $(X,A,U)$ of spaces *excision enabled* if both $(X,A)$ and $(X \backslash U, A \backslash U)$ belong to $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\overline{U} \subset int(A)$.

($\ast$) The class of excision enabled triples is strictly larger than class of excision enabled triples with an open $U$.

This is certainly true for $\mathfrak{T}^2$.

Comment: Interesting.  What was their proof that the open version implies the stronger?   Does it work for any theory?

Comment: @Randall Eilenberg and Steenrod proved directly from the definition of the singular chain complex that the stronger variant is satisfied. They *did not show* that the open version implies the stronger, that is, their proof does not generalize to other theories.