# Question on the excision axiom (Hatcher vs Spanier)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have noticed that in Hatcher's book (pg 201) the excision axiom for singular cohomology asserts that  for triples $Z\subset A\subset X$ with $\overline{Z} \subset \mathrm{int}A$ then the map induced by the inclusion
$$i^* : H^n(X, A; \ G)\to H^n(X\setminus Z, A\setminus Z;\  G)$$ induces an isomorphism.
On the other hand, if we look at Spanier's book Algebraic Topology pg. 200, the excision axiom requires an additional hypothesis, namely that $Z$ is an *open* subset of $X$.

Of course Hatcher's definition implies Spanier's but I do not see why these are equivalent.

> 1. Are these form of excision equivalent?
>
> 2. Same question but for Alexander-Spanier cohomology and Cech cohomology.

Comment: This has been discussed before here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892961/non-equivalence-of-two-variants-of-the-excision-axiom. Not sure how much help this is to you.

Comment: I see, it is without answer though, and the post is old, maybe somebody today has an answer.

Comment: Spanier proves a bit more. Lemma 4  on p. 309 implies that excision is valid for $Z \subset A$ such that $Z \subset W \subset \bar W \subset \text{int} A$ for some open $W \subset X$. But it is still weaker than "usual excision".

Comment: Clarification concerning Spanier: Spanier proves the above variant of excision for Alexander-Spanier-cohomology. In his book there is no general result about the relationship between various variants.