# Weaker Condition for the Excision Axiom

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The excision axiom in homology states that if $\overline Z\subseteq\operatorname{Int}A$, then $h_n(X\setminus Z,A\setminus Z)$ is isomorphic to $h_n(X,A)$, where the map is induced by the inclusion.

What I want to ask is the following. Suppose I can prove the isomorphism for the special case that $Z$ is closed and $A$ is open with $Z\subseteq A$, would it imply the excision axiom?

If that is not enough, suppose I remove the restriction that $A$ is open, and I can prove this for the special case that $Z$ is closed (no requirement on $A$), would that suffice?

Comment: This is a very subtle question and I doubt that the answer is "yes". I also doubt that you will get an answer at all. I asked a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2892961.